# Arithmetic Using Different Bases

Tags: elementary-number-theory

If $Feed_{base 8}-Feed_{base 5}=Feed_{base 7}$, then what do the digits $F, e$, and $d$ stand for?

So far I have that $d = 5$ and $e = 6$. I think those are correct. However, I am getting stuck on figuring out what number $F$ stands for. Any insight would be greatly appreciated, and if I have $d$ and $e$ incorrect, please let me know why.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

First $d$ and $e$ cannot be more than $4$ since you are using base $5$.

Note that
$$Feed_8=d+8e+64e+512f$$
$$Feed_5=d+5e+25e+125f$$
$$Feed_7=d+7e+49e+343f$$

Just plug these in the equation, and use the fact that $0 \leq f,e, d \leq 4$. The solution should be easy to get.

Comment: That makes much more sense than what I was trying to do. I was using the words literally instead of breaking them down using their respective bases. I got $F = 1, e = 3$, and $d = 2$.